# Combining and Grouping By Dates using a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, attributeerror

I have a data column in my Pandas data frame that looks like the following:

```
Date
========
2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
2022-01-01T08:00:00.000Z    
2022-01-01T16:00:00.000Z
2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
2022-01-02T08:00:00.000Z    
2022-01-02T16:00:00.000Z
```

I am trying to reformat the dates into `%Y-%m-%d` form, so I can perform a `groupby` operation on the dates.

I am currently trying to run this line of code

```
CombinedData['Date'] = CombinedData['Date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

but I keep getting an `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`. I am a little confused on why this error is occurring since my dates are formatted as dates in my data frame. Why is this happening, and what can I do to mend this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
CombinedData['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(CombinedData['Date']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```